# Why can't I read registers through SPI on STM32?

Tags: c++, c, stm32, spi

I'm trying to connect a LSM6DSOX sensor board with SPI to the Nucleo-STM32L011K4. It looks like I can succesfully read to the board, and I use the following code for it:

```
static int32_t platform_write(void *handle, uint8_t reg, uint8_t *bufp,
                              uint16_t len)
{
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, CS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    BSP_SPI1_Send(&reg, 1);
    BSP_SPI1_Send(bufp, len);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, CS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I try to read from a single register, like the WHO_AM_I register, I always get back 0x00 (which should not be the case). I use the following code for reading:

```
static int32_t platform_read(void *handle, uint8_t reg, uint8_t *bufp,
                             uint16_t len)
{
    reg |= 0x80;
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA , CS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    BSP_SPI1_Send(&reg, 1);
    BSP_SPI1_Recv(bufp, len);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, CS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    return 0;
}
```

I can not figure out why this does not work. I thought many other code-parts were the problem, but I think I narrowed it down to this part. Anyone can spot an error?

Comment: which line gives an unexpected result? BSP_SPI1_Recv(bufp, len);? Is the 0x00 in bufp? Why do you set GPIOB after resetting GPIOA?

Comment: @Sebastian Yes, the bufp gets 0x00. That's why I thought there might be something wrong there. Thanks for noticing the GPIOA/B stuff. I replaced that, but now the firmware does not even work anymore

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable register address increment.
See datasheet for LSM6DSOX. In register CTRL3_C(12h) set she bit IF_INC.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).